# what are the difference between __proto__ and prototype?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [];
console.dir(myArray);
```

Returns `__proto__` not prototype:

[image]

```
console.dir(Array);
```

Return both `prototype and __proto__` but but **opposite** than above.

[image]

- In first case: `__proto__` has concat, constructor, etc.
- In second    case: `prototype` has concat, constructor, etc.

So, why is this returning different results?

Comment: Because the first is an instance, and the second the constructor function (or "class" if you want)

Comment: `Array._proto_` === Function.prototype and `myArray._proto_` === Array.prototype. Why? Because myArray is an instance of Array so Array's prototype === `myArray._proto_`. The prototype of Array is the first used in the prototype chain for myArray. Array is an instance of Function so `Array._proto_` === Function.prototype. That is why you can do `Array.call({})` (not that that does anything) For more info about constructor functions and prototype see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941